# What is the M1.9 UPS Shipping Default Rate Table (out of the box, not XML)

Tags: magento-1.9, api, shipping, ups

We are doing some comparisons with our different options using M1.9 UPS shipping. We noticed that the rate for the default UPS setting for UPS Type (United Parcel Service) is returning values that are NOT our negotiated rates (obviously) but NOT either their Retail rates or Published rates either. Does anybody know what rate table this is referencing? We are using Pickup Method (Regular Daily Pickup) but even when changing that we still are not seeing a match for anything from our portal.

We will be switching to XML but I really want to know what this rogue table might be while we develop our strategy.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advanced for helping out a newbie.

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: I did run in debug and check the log files and everything looks legit there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been able to get any clarification from UPS. Is there any hope by calling magentos 800#? 1 877 574 5093?